# Generalized parameter

Tags: c++

I am wondering if it is possible to have a function parameter and not care what its type is. 
For example, I have a class with overriden << operator. The only thing it does, though, is add the param to private ostringstream:

```
CLog& CLog::operator <<(const char * txt) {
    buffer << txt;
    return *this;
}
```

However, this only allows me to write const char to the buffer. I need the parameter to be any type `ostringstream <<` accepts. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use templates:

```
template <typename T>
CLog& CLog::operator <<(const T& p) {
    buffer << p;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with templates:

```
template <class T>
Clog& Clog::operator <<(const T& t) {
    buffer << t;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `template` in this case.

```
template<class T>
CLog& Clog::operator <<(const T& value) {
    buffer << value;
    return *this;
}
```

Make sure you don't pass anything that's invalid for `ofstringstream` though.

Comment: Wow. 3 second differences between 3 almost identical answers. :v
I don't see that very often on the other forums I hang out on.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer are basically correct, but they don't support move operations. Use

```
template <typename T>
CLog& CLog::operator <<(T&& p) {
    buffer << std::forward<T>(p);
    return *this;
}
```